# In what ways is bx better than ax

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am currently learning assembly 8086.
Some of the commands work with ax and some don't.
for example: mov [ax], 5 doesn't work.
Why is this and what are the advantages of the bx register over ax register?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The letter `b` has a higher ascii value than `a` so that makes `b` superior;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main advantage of `bx` over `ax` is that it can be referred to as
a pointer to an address in the data segment.

You can't use `ax` in an effective address:

```
MOV cx, [ax]     ;doesn't work
MOV cx, [bx]     ;works fine and loads cx with the value which is pointed by bx
```

The registers that you can refer to as pointers are:
`bx`, `si`, `di`, `bp`

and those are the ones that can't be referred to as pointers:
`ax`, `cx`, `dx`, `sp`

This is a limitation of [16bit addressing modes](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~celio/mc404s2-03/addr_modes/intel_addr.html).  See also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.

---

`ax` has an advantage in math operations as some functions such as `mul` use it implicitly.
`mul cx` multiples the ax by cx and stores the result in `dx:ax`.  On a 386 or later, you can use for example `imul bx, cx` to do `bx *= cx`.  It's a longer OpCode, and only produces the low half of the multiply result (which is the same regardless of signed vs. unsigned, which is why there's no two or three operand form of `mul`).

`div` and `idiv` only have single-operand forms that divide `dx:ax` by the source operand, storing the results in dx and ax.

8086 also needs `ax` for more things than later CPUs, because it doesn't have `movsx`, so you need to put bytes in `al` to run `cbw`.

Comment: Do you have a reference for your last statement?

Comment: Yes I do, for example the `mul` operation multiplies a specified value or register specifically be ax and stores the result in dx:ax

Comment: No, you can't use `dx`, `sp` or `ip` in effective addresses.

Comment: Just checked it with the debugger, your'e right I will correct/make the last statement more clear, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: _"you can use imul bx, 5 if you wish but it's OpCode is much longer and works only with unsigned integer multiplication"_  `mul` is the unsigned variant. `imul` performs signed multiplication.

Comment: "and works only with unsigned integer multiplication" it's exactly what I stated.

Comment: And that's wrong, doubly. `imul` is signed **but** the 2 or 3 operand version works fine for both signed and unsigned, as the instruction set reference also mentions. Same doesn't go for `div`/`idiv`.

Comment: yup, this answer had many mistakes, even though the main point was correct.  I fixed it up to be correct, since that was possible without changing Elian's meaning or intent, IMO.

Comment: @PeterCordes `lea cx, [bx + bx*4]` is illegal, just saying :)

Comment: @jester: dammit, you're right, I forgot 16bit didn't have scaled indexing.  I put that in since Elian had mentioned using the immediate form of imul to multiply by 5 (which is a totally bogus thing to do in 32bit or 64bit code, since LEA does the job better).  It's interesting that the immediate form of imul has a separate destination operand, since it has a whole opcode to itself, instead of borrowing the `/r` field of the mod/rm byte.  (And doesn't have a longer opcode; it's only the 2-reg form that uses `OF AF`).

Comment: @PeterCordes What you added is surely useful, but I'm not sure that making radical edits to answers is "fine" according to the SO question model.

Comment: @black: It's still a very recent post, so I'm assuming Elian is still around to review the change and rewrite any of the corrections into his own words / formatting if he wants.  If this was an older post, I probably wouldn't have been so cavalier, and maybe just left a comment.  Or maybe still fixed things, but not have thrown in the extra link and sutff.  I realize it's pushing the boundaries for an acceptable edit, at least by some people's standards.  re: Elian's comment below: glad you like it, you're welcome :)  I did add new info though: `movsx` and the 386-only issue.

Comment: I am not sure how "radical" the changes for the original post are, the points are the same, Peter enhanced the post by making it more detailed and clear (which I thank him for). I don't see any model violation in the edit, neither new information was added nor the main points and even the flow and order of information retained its original state. exactly the opposite, Peter's edit is exactly what an edit should be, a refinement of the post.

Answer (score 4):

> For example: `mov [ax], 5` doesn't work. Why is this?

Because in 16-bit addressing there's no [SIB byte](http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#SIB), which is used in 32-bit addressing to allow things like `[eax + ecx * 4]`. And the available ModR/M byte combinations were chosen to encode [other effective addresses](http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#16-bit_addressing), such as `[bx+si]` and `[bp+di]`.